# How rewrite R for(){} function from dplyr to data.table?

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, data.table

I have this for(){} inside a function that read specific file columns in a folder. But as I have several files it is very slow.

**How could I rewrite this in data.table format?**

I use arrange(), because after I will bind this two df's by name. Name are equal in files, but not equally ordered in these. It's necessary bind columns class1 and class2 by name for this I use arrange().

```
for (i in 1:length(temp)) {
    
    df1 <- read_table(temp[[i]],
                      col_types = "c________________f__",
                      col_names = c("name", "class1")) %>% 
      arrange(name)
    
    df2 <- read_table(str_remove(temp[[i]], "_automat"),
                      col_types = "c________________f__",
                      col_names = c("name", "class2")) %>% 
      arrange(name)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to convert this to data.tables, you can switch from `read_table` to `fread`, which is supposed to be faster and which generate a data.table which [you can sort with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11559127/fastest-by-column-sort-in-r) `[order(*)]`:

```
library(data.table)

fread(file=temp[[i]], select = c(name='character', class1='numeric'))[order(name)]
```

That might increase your speed some, but I think if you want more significant improvements, I'd look into replacing your `for` loop with a parallel `foreach` loop from the `foreach` package. There are a number of questions talking about how to do that, but you might want to start here: [run a for loop in parallel in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38318139/run-a-for-loop-in-parallel-in-r)

Comment: setorder is likely to be faster than order